# How to use array_diff for same value used multiple times within an array?

Tags: php, arrays

I've two different arrays with multiple values, they are as follows,

```
$a1 = ['a','b','c','sadasd','sadasd','sadasd','sadasd'];
$b1 = ['d','a','c','sadasd'];

$removed = array_diff($a1,$b1);
$added = array_diff($a1,$b1);
```

Now `array_diff` works perfectly but I'm facing issue for differentiating with same name value used multiple times

What I'm getting right now is

```
$removed =>

Array
(
    [1] => b
)

$added => 

Array
(
    [0] => d
)
```

Which is original behaviour of `array_diff` but, how to get result something like as

```
$removed =>

Array
(
    [1] => b
    [4] => sadasd
    [5] => sadasd
    [6] => sadasd
)
```

Comment: There is not a built in for this you'll have to roll your own.

Comment: Do you have any idea about this @nerdlyist

Comment: You should try and then come back if you have issues.